# Removing specific widgets from specific pages

Tags: wordpress

I have specific pages that I need specific widgets to be hidden from the sidebar. I have

-5 pages that are supposed to only display nav_menu-1

-6 other pages that are supposed to display only nav_menu-2

-and then all single-posts that are supposed to only show nav_menu-3

I have this code

```
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'widget_display_2', 50, 3 );
function widget_display_2( $instance, $widget, $args ){
if ( is_single() && $widget->id == 'nav_menu-1' ) {
    return false;
}
return $instance;
}
```

but what is the best way to insert all my pages and widget IDs to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

It may sound weird but why not using three different sidebars and call them by condition. This way your Theme would become more flexible. It´s always bad to hardcode this into your theme or plugin.

```
// Register Sidebars
function custom_sidebars() {

$args = array(
    'id'            => 'custom-sidebar-1',
    'name'          => __( 'Custom Sidebar 1', 'text_domain' ),
);
register_sidebar( $args );

$args = array(
    'id'            => 'custom-sidebar-2',
    'name'          => __( 'Custom Sidebar 2', 'text_domain' ),
);
register_sidebar( $args );

$args = array(
    'id'            => 'custom-sidebar-3',
    'name'          => __( 'Custom Sidebar 3', 'text_domain' ),
);
register_sidebar( $args );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_sidebars' );
```

... after you added this to your functions.php you can call the different sidebars with conditional functions.

```
<?php
/** call custom sidebar on single.php template **/
if ( is_single() ){
dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-sidebar-1' );
}
?>

<?php
/** call custom sidebar on page.php template (all pages) **/
if ( is_page() ){
dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-sidebar-2' );
}
?>

<?php
/** call custom sidebar on multiple pages by id **/
if ( is_page( array( 11, 22, 33, 44 ) ) ){
dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-sidebar-3' );
}
?>
```

Comment: I can't really get this to work. I actually added the sidebar calls into the sidebar.php of my theme and removed the rgeular sidebar call, and then it did work, but now every first menu link in the sideabr has a bullet in front, even though everything is set to list-style:none;  Not sure if this is really the best way?

Comment: This sounds more like a css problem. Can you show a link?

Comment: As a alernative you could use a plugin like https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-widgets/